# Reversing audio digits of audio object

Tags: sound

My question is about reversing the integers of an audio object file's data.

If I make an audio object, and I wish to convert the audio-data to integers between 0 and 10000, I then wish to access the effect of reversing the sequence of the audio integers.

Thus, if I were to take one audio sample, and the integer associated with it were 5691, the the reverse of this is 1965.

I need to apply the `IntegerReverse` function to ALL of the audio samples in my audio object, and when I tried the following code, I get some error messages, and I sort of do not know what they mean exactly.

```
AudioPlay[IntegerReverse[Round[Abs[(10000*
  Audio["F:\\Mr. SRU-Hobbies and Interests 2006-2020\\Find Sounds \ Samples, And Wavs To Use\\Find Sounds\\softmiddleC.wav"])]]]
]
```

The error message was:

> AudioStream: An internal error occurred: the provided function did not generate a buffer of audio samples.

Please advise.

Comment: If my answer seems childish, I beg for your forgiveness. Please remember that I am a beginner to Mathematica. I entered, this:                  
                                                                                                                      
 AudioPlay[IntegerReverse[Round[Abs[(10000*
      Audio["F:\\Mr. SRU-Hobbies and Interests 2006-2020\\Find Sounds Samples, And Wavs To Use\\Find Sounds\\softmiddleC.wav"])]]]]   the error message was:      AudioStream: An internal error occurred: the provided function did not generate a buffer of audio samples.

Comment: Yes, indeed! I believe that I might have done it. I got Mathematica to apply the digit reversal to the audio sample. At least, I think I have...-and...-The results?/Noise, and intermittent static. I guess, that...-The fact that the mind perceived a pattern in the data, -however... does not necessarily follow that the ear will. I do have many other projects that I need doing, so please bear with me and in due course I will send them to Maths Stack Exchange, OK?

Comment: Yes, indeed, I did this on a pure tone output by Audacity...-and a regular waveform was produced with this digit reversal process. I believe that it might be doing what I wanted to, but the thing is to experiment with different multipliers and different number bases, because BOTH of these things are relevant and will drastically effect the output of a sound when altered by the IntegerReverse function of Mathematica....and, as you say, -yes, indeed 00001 becomes 10000 under this function...A word of many thanks for all your help and the people of Maths Stack Exchange (MSE).

Comment: Yes! You are on to it! Something like 7.564 would become:7564 if I multiplied it by 1000, and then this reversed would be:4657. But, depending on the amount of decimal places you had, -this would alter the sound. I also used an abs and then a rounding function in Mathematica AFTER I multiplied by 10000, but I could have just as easily have multiped by 100, 10000000, or even 10, -and then took the abs function then rounded. As I said, the result will differ greatly depending on what you multiply by and also what base you used. I would dearly like to her you people's ideas and comments!

Comment: Something has just occurred to me, however...And this is: How can I be ABSOLTUELY CERRTAIN that Mathematica is altering the audio data in the "correct way"..-I mean, the code, -it was altering it, but how can I be totally and one hundred percent/absolutely sure that it has altered the audio data in the way that the code says? Any ideas? Please advise.

Comment: The discussion in comments appears to have strayed from the original question. I will suggest closing this and, if needed, opening a new one that addresses the actual matter(s).

Comment: Ok, I understand. I will have to be very careful about what I say. The rules of this forum appear to be VERY strict to me. I will be studying this year in 2021 at my local University, so I hope to find a Mathematica tutor, or at least someone who uses it up there...If so, I can ask them these sorts of questions...Anyway, -I am  pretty sure that Mathematica did alter the audio file that I put into it correctly...I am just a little uncertain. Can I please have permission to continue this thread of conversation?

Comment: Actually, I have been giving this some thought, and, yes, you are correct... come to think of it we do seem to be getting a bit off topic. So, I will start a new question...OK?OK!